# How to reorder 1st dim of array in R (don't know total dims)

Tags: arrays, r, indexing, subset

I have an array whose first dimension I need to subset/ index/ reorder. For example:

```
arr <- array(1:24, dim=c(4,3,2))
arr[4:1,,]
```

Simple, works like a charm.

**However, is there a way to do this when I'm unsure how many dimensions the array has?** To be clear, I will always know the size of that first dimension (i.e., I know `dim(arr)[1]`), I just don't know `length(dim(arr))`.

Comment: Do you mean that for some reason you can't query `length(dim(arr))`? Or just that you don't know it in advance?

Comment: @jbaums I don't know how many commas to type. I wish I could just do `arr[4:1,...]` or something. So I don't know `length(dim(arr))` in advanced, but it can be queried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a weird alternative. This idea is based on an implementation quirk I noticed at one point, that R seems to represent "missing" function arguments as [symbols](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/name.html) with zero-length names. One of the reasons that this is so bizarre is that R normally doesn't allow you to create symbols with zero-length names:

```
as.symbol('');
## Error in as.symbol("") : attempt to use zero-length variable name
```

But through some messing around, I discovered that you can slip past R's defenses by accessing the parse tree of an expression that involves a "missing" argument, and indexing out the element of the parse tree that contains the "missing" argument. Here's a demo of some of the weird behavior you get from this thing:

```
substitute(x[]); ## parse tree involving missing argument
## x[]
as.list(substitute(x[])); ## show list representation; third component is the guy
## [[1]]
## `[`
##
## [[2]]
## x
##
## [[3]]
##
##
substitute(x[])[[3]]; ## prints nothing!
##
(function(x) c(typeof(x),mode(x),class(x)))(substitute(x[])[[3]]); ## it's a symbol alright
## [1] "symbol" "name"   "name"
as.character(substitute(x[])[[3]]); ## gets the name of the symbol: the empty string!
## [1] ""
i.dont.exist <- substitute(x[])[[3]]; ## store in variable
i.dont.exist; ## wha??
## Error: argument "i.dont.exist" is missing, with no default
```

Anyway, here's the solution we can derive for the OP's problem:

```
arr <- array(1:24,4:2);
do.call(`[`,c(list(arr,4:1),rep(list(substitute(x[])[[3]]),length(dim(arr))-1)));
## , , 1
##
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    4    8   12
## [2,]    3    7   11
## [3,]    2    6   10
## [4,]    1    5    9
##
## , , 2
##
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]   16   20   24
## [2,]   15   19   23
## [3,]   14   18   22
## [4,]   13   17   21
##
```

<s>I was hoping it would outperform all the other solutions, but @thelatemail, you win this round:</s> Aha! I realized that we can precompute a list of an empty symbol (storing an empty symbol in a variable by itself, i.e. *not* in a list, is not usable, as I showed above) and `rep()` that list in the solution, rather than incurring all the overhead of `substitute()` to parse out a dummy expression in every invocation of the solution. And behold the performance:

```
straight <- function() arr[4:1,,];
jb <- function() do.call(`[`,c(list(arr,4:1),lapply(dim(arr)[-1],seq_len)));
tlm <- function() do.call(`[`,c(list(arr,4:1),rep(TRUE,length(dim(arr))-1)));
orderD1 <- function(x,ord) { dims <- dim(x); ndim <- length(dims); stopifnot(ndim>0); if (ndim==1) return(x[ord]); wl_i <- which(letters=="i"); dimLetters <- letters[wl_i:(wl_i+ndim-1)]; dimList <- structure(vector("list",ndim),.Names=dimLetters); dimList[[1]] <- ord; for (i in 2:ndim) dimList[[i]] <- 1:dims[i]; do.call("[",c(list(x=x),dimList)); };
rbatt <- function() orderD1(arr,4:1);
bgoldst <- function() do.call(`[`,c(list(arr,4:1),rep(list(substitute(x[])[[3]]),length(dim(arr))-1)));
ls0 <- list(substitute(x[])[[3]]);
ls0;
## [[1]]
##
##
bgoldst2 <- function() do.call(`[`,c(list(arr,4:1),rep(ls0,length(dim(arr))-1)));

microbenchmark(straight(),jb(),tlm(),rbatt(),bgoldst(),bgoldst2(),times=1e5);
## Unit: nanoseconds
##        expr   min    lq      mean median    uq      max neval
##  straight()   428   856  1161.038    856  1284   998142 1e+05
##        jb()  4277  5988  7136.534   6843  7271  1629357 1e+05
##       tlm()  2566  3850  4622.668   4277  4705  1704196 1e+05
##     rbatt() 24804 28226 31975.583  29509 31219 34970873 1e+05
##   bgoldst()  3421  4705  5601.300   5132  5560  1918878 1e+05
##  bgoldst2()  2566  3850  4533.383   4277  4705  1034065 1e+05
```

---

Just discovered that there's an easier way to get ahold of the empty symbol, which seems to have been available all along:

```
substitute();
##
```

My `substitute(x[])[[3]]` trick now looks kind of stupid.

Out of curiosity I benchmarked using `substitute()` directly against the other solutions, and it incurs a slight performance cost compared to `bgoldst2()`, making it slightly worse than `tlm()`:

```
bgoldst3 <- function() do.call(`[`,c(list(arr,4:1),rep(list(substitute()),length(dim(arr))-1)));
microbenchmark(straight(),jb(),tlm(),rbatt(),bgoldst(),bgoldst2(),bgoldst3(),times=1e5);
## Unit: nanoseconds
##        expr   min    lq      mean median    uq      max neval
##  straight()   428   856  1069.340    856  1284   850603 1e+05
##        jb()  4277  5988  6916.899   6416  7270  2978180 1e+05
##       tlm()  2566  3849  4307.979   4277  4704  3138122 1e+05
##     rbatt() 24377 28226 30882.666  29508 30364 36768360 1e+05
##   bgoldst()  2994  4704  5165.019   5132  5560  2050171 1e+05
##  bgoldst2()  2566  3849  4232.816   4277  4278  1085813 1e+05
##  bgoldst3()  2566  3850  4545.508   4277  4705  1004131 1e+05
```

Comment: That's awesome. Darn near tied with `tlm()`. I might have to edit my function later to drop out all of the naming and checks etc just to see if it gets into the same ballpark as those others. Super cool info on the symbol for missing thing. I'll have to think about that.

Comment: Although you are getting a tiny advantage by taking the `substitute()` and `list` call outside of the benchmark. Regardless, it is an interesting little investigation.

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, that's a fair point. But since it's possible to precompute `ls0` just once in any R session, I think it does make sense to consider that cost to be amortized over all runs of the solution in that session. But even with that, our times are so close that we can basically consider this a tie. And your solution has the advantage that it's entirely self-contained (no precomputation is necessary), and it doesn't depend on an obscure implementation detail of the language.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one possible way, though it's still a bit slow.

```
do.call(`[`, c(list(arr, 4:1), lapply(dim(arr)[-1], seq_len)))

## , , 1
## 
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    4    8   12
## [2,]    3    7   11
## [3,]    2    6   10
## [4,]    1    5    9
## 
## , , 2
## 
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]   16   20   24
## [2,]   15   19   23
## [3,]   14   18   22
## [4,]   13   17   21
```

`do.call` requires a list of arguments that (if unnamed) will be passed to the specified function (in this case, `[`) in the order in which they're supplied.

Above, we pass a list, `list(arr, 4:1, 1:3, 1:2)` to `[`, which is equivalent to doing: `` `[`(arr, 4:1, 1:3, 1:2) `` (which, in turn, is equivalent to `arr[4:1, 1:3, 1:2]`).

Timing:

```
microbenchmark(subset=arr[4:1,,], 
               jb=do.call(`[`, c(list(arr, 4:1), lapply(dim(arr)[-1], seq_len))), 
               times=1E3)


## Unit: microseconds
##   expr   min     lq      mean median     uq    max neval
## subset 1.140  1.711  1.765575  1.711  1.711 15.395  1000
##     jb 9.693 10.834 11.464768 11.404 11.974 96.365  1000
```

(Ignore absolute times - my system is currently under strain.)

So, it takes around ten times as long as the straightforward subset. Probably room for improvement here, though as @thelatemail comments, the timings are much more comparable on larger arrays.

---

**EDIT**

As suggested by @thelatemail, the index sequences can be replaced by `TRUE`, which will speed things up a bit.

```
do.call(`[`, c(list(arr, 4:1), rep(TRUE, length(dim(arr))-1)))
```

Timings again:

```
microbenchmark(subset=arr[4:1,,], 
               jb=do.call(`[`, c(list(arr, 4:1), lapply(dim(arr)[-1], seq_len))),
               tlm=do.call(`[`, c(list(arr, 4:1), rep(TRUE, length(dim(arr)) - 1))),
               times=1E3)

## Unit: microseconds
##    expr    min     lq      mean median     uq     max neval
##  subset  1.140  1.711  2.146474  1.711  2.281 124.875  1000
##      jb 10.834 11.974 13.455343 12.545 13.685 293.086  1000
##     tlm  6.272  7.413  8.348592  7.983  8.553  95.795  1000
```

Comment: It's also not that slow, try it with `arr <- arr[,,rep(1,1e4)]` and the relative advantage mostly slips away.

Comment: Nice, much more succinct than mine (no checks etc; also I guess I didn't need to name the args hehe; good job on the `seq_len`). I had originally tried doing a `NULL` instead of the whole `seq_len` bit, but that didn't work. I just want to leave those other dims `missing()` or something ... idk. But this looks ~right.

Comment: `TRUE` is another placeholder that will work when you want to pass a missing value to `[` instead, e.g. `arr[TRUE,TRUE,1]` or `do.call(\`[\`, list(arr,TRUE,TRUE,1) )`

Comment: @thelatemail - nice, I didn't know that. That'll be a bit more efficient, too.

Comment: @jbaums - nice edit, even using TRUE I couldn't get it faster because I was complicating the `list` and `c` parts. You've fixed that!

Comment: @thelatemail - list concatenation often baffles me ... I usually get the `c`/`as.list`/`list` incantation wrong the first time ;)

Comment: @thelatemail Nice with the `TRUE`. But, @jbaums can't you just rely on recycling to repeat the `TRUE`? I.e., I think that's why `(1:10)[TRUE]` returns the full vector .. it recycles. Same could be done here?

Comment: @rbatt - that's the idea, but for `(1:10)[TRUE]` you just have a single vector, whereas we have an unknown number of vectors for which `TRUE` would be recycled. We need to pass a list of _n_ `TRUE`s to `[` via `do.call`, where _n_ is `length(dim(arr)) - 1`. (tl;dr ... it won't recycle across dimensions)

Answer (score 2):

I have an ugly and inefficient solution. The problem with a simpler approach is I don't know how to implement the defaults of `[` properly using `do.call`. Maybe someone will see this and be inspired.

#### Here is the function:

```
orderD1 <- function(x, ord){    
    dims <- dim(x)
    ndim <- length(dims)

    stopifnot(ndim>0)

    if(ndim==1){
        return(x[ord])
    }

    wl_i <- which(letters=="i")
    dimLetters <- letters[wl_i:(wl_i+ndim-1)]

    dimList <- structure(vector("list",ndim), .Names=dimLetters)
    dimList[[1]] <- ord
    for(i in 2:ndim){
        dimList[[i]] <- 1:dims[i]
    }
    do.call("[",c(list(x=x),dimList))
}
```

#### Here is an implementation using the example in the question:

```
orderD1(arr, 4:1)

, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    8   12
[2,]    3    7   11
[3,]    2    6   10
[4,]    1    5    9

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   16   20   24
[2,]   15   19   23
[3,]   14   18   22
[4,]   13   17   21
```

#### An example of how slow this is ...

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(arr[4:1,,], orderD1(arr, 4:1), times=1E3)
Unit: nanoseconds
              expr   min    lq      mean median      uq    max neval
      arr[4:1, , ]   864  1241  1445.876   1451  1596.0  17191  1000
 orderD1(arr, 4:1) 52020 54061 56286.856  54909 56194.5 179363  1000
```

I would gladly accept a more elegant/ compact solution.

Comment: `apply(arr, 2:(length(dim(arr))), rev)` maybe?

Comment: @thelatemail I like where your head is at. Generalize it to switch out `rev` for something like `function(x)do.call("[",list(x=x,i=ord))`. Idk, my brain is pretty tired right now. Work up and answer and show the results +1 for the comment, answer!

Comment: Also worth keeping in mind that you have an average time difference here of `0.00005` seconds.

Comment: @thelatemail Not sure how it scales though